# C# - Are type conversions (numbers to char) made based on ASCII values?

Tags: c#, types, char, type-conversion, short

I'm new to C#, and I'm trying to understand more about data types and conversion. I have the following console program:

```
using System;

namespace First_lesson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char singleLetter = 'B';
            short num = 291;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", num, singleLetter);


            singleLetter = Convert.ToChar(num);
            Console.WriteLine(singleLetter);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", sizeof(short), sizeof(char));

        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why, when I convert `num` to a `char`, I get a lowercase **g** instead of the hashtag symbol **#**.

[image]

Isn't the conversion made based on ASCII values?

Comment: Is this `Convert.ToChar` satisfy you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hkfdkcx(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: "Converts the value of the specified 32-bit signed integer to its equivalent Unicode character." - the conversion ultimately based on UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is an encoding for the the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. `char` has a range from 0 to 0xffff so I can't see why you'd expect 291 to map '#'.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToChar` returns a `char` (which is a UTF-16 code unit) that has the specified numeric value.

`291` (decimal) is the same as `0x123` (hex), so `Convert.ToChar(291)` returns a `char` containing the [character `U+0123`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0123/index.htm), which is LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH CEDILLA, i.e., `ģ`.

When you print this to a non-Unicode console, the accent is stripped off and an ASCII `g` is printed instead.

Answer (score 0):

> The char keyword is used to declare an instance of the System.Char structure that the .NET Framework uses to represent a Unicode character. The value of a Char object is a 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value.

Actually, one char represents a `Unicode` character. 35 in decimal is the representation of `#` sign

```
public static void Main()
{
    char singleLetter = 'B';
    short num = 35;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", num, singleLetter);

    singleLetter = Convert.ToChar(num);
    Console.WriteLine(singleLetter);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", sizeof(short), sizeof(char));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Try this:

```
short singleLetter = Convert.ToInt16('B');
Console.WriteLine(singleLetter);
```

`B` is the `66` decimal value
You can use [this](https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) page as a reference for the `Unicode` table